# OpenVPN dns not working properly, invalid prefix

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, openvpn

I am trying to establish a VPN tunnel with OpenVPN to access a remote Kubernetes cluster. The connection itself can be established and I am assigned an IP address.

Connection logs:

`Sat Apr 27 12:42:39 2019 OpenVPN 2.4.4 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Sep  5 2018
Sat Apr 27 12:42:39 2019 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017, LZO 2.08
Sat Apr 27 12:42:39 2019 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Sat Apr 27 12:42:39 2019 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET] ADDR
Sat Apr 27 12:42:39 2019 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]ADDR [nonblock]
Sat Apr 27 12:42:40 2019 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]ADDR
Sat Apr 27 12:42:40 2019 TCP_CLIENT link local: (not bound)
Sat Apr 27 12:42:40 2019 TCP_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]ADDR
Sat Apr 27 12:42:40 2019 WARNING: 'keydir' is present in remote config but missing in local config, remote='keydir 0'
Sat Apr 27 12:42:40 2019 [server] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]ADDR
Sat Apr 27 12:42:41 2019 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Sat Apr 27 12:42:41 2019 do_ifconfig, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Sat Apr 27 12:42:41 2019 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Sat Apr 27 12:42:41 2019 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 10.240.0.26 peer 10.240.0.25
Error: Invalid prefix for given prefix length.
Sat Apr 27 12:42:41 2019 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
Sat Apr 27 12:42:41 2019 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Sat Apr 27 12:42:41 2019 Initialization Sequence Completed`

The following lines suggest the problem: 

`Error: Invalid prefix for given prefix length.
Sat Apr 27 12:42:41 2019 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2`

I am currently using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. The same error occurred on an other system with Arch Linux as well as a VM with Ubuntu inside my Ubuntu System.

Furthermore, I have disabled IPv6 system wide without success.

A coworker of mine is using Windows and he is able to establish a VPN tunnel with working dns.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're trying to disable IPv6 when the error message shows up after trying to add an IPv4 address?

Comment: Yes you are right. I am not sure how to debug these kind of problems. Therefore, I tried to disable as many error sources as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not around DNS but when open vpn calls `add route` returning error status 2.
You should look into your config file to make sure the route is added properly.

Comment: Are you talking about the server configuration? In that case, why is it working on a windows machine?

Comment: I think the issue is on the client side when open vpn is trying to add a route to your client machine.